# How to debug viewlet creation in Plone using browserlayer

Tags: plone

I'm often faced to overriding viewlet issues and often I don't find why it will works or not.

I'm now trying to override the collective.googleanalytics tracker viewlet which use a browserlayer but do not inherits from plone.app.layout.viewlets.common.BaseViewlet.

To achieve this I have created a browserlayer that inherits from c.googleanalytics one, registred it and verified everthings goes well.

I still don't understand why the c.googleanalytics viewlet is used instead of mine.

Code is here: https://github.com/toutpt/collective.linguaanalytics

I would like to be able to know where I can add PDB to debug this. or what tools can help.

Edit:

```
(Pdb) self.request.__provides__.__iro__
InterfaceClass plonetheme.sunburst.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific>, 
InterfaceClass plone.app.z3cform.interfaces.IPloneFormLayer>, 
InterfaceClass z3c.form.interfaces.IFormLayer>, 
InterfaceClass plone.app.discussion.interfaces.IDiscussionLayer>, 
InterfaceClass collective.linguaanalytics.interfaces.ILayer>, 
InterfaceClass collective.googleanalytics.interfaces.browserlayer.IAnalyticsLayer>, InterfaceClass plone.theme.interfaces.IDefaultPloneLayer>, 
InterfaceClass Products.CMFDefault.interfaces.ICMFDefaultSkin>, 
InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IDefaultBrowserLayer>, 
InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IBrowserRequest>, 
InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.http.IHTTPRequest>, 
InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.IRequest>, 
InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.IPublisherRequest>, 
InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.IPublicationRequest>, 
InterfaceClass zope.security.interfaces.IParticipation>, 
InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.IApplicationRequest>, 
InterfaceClass zope.interface.common.mapping.IEnumerableMapping>, 
InterfaceClass zope.interface.common.mapping.IReadMapping>,
InterfaceClass zope.interface.common.mapping.IItemMapping>, 
InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.ISkinnable>, 
InterfaceClass zope.annotation.interfaces.IAttributeAnnotatable>, 
InterfaceClass zope.annotation.interfaces.IAnnotatable>, 
InterfaceClass zope.interface.Interface>)
```

Edit:
It seems they are no tests around the override of layer by an other layer in plone.browserlayer. May be a bug ?

Comment: That is odd. Your code looks correct since you extend IAnalyticsLayer in your ILayer. Only thing that looks a little fishy is when you remove the "analytics" browser layer in your GS profile.

Comment: Stick a pdb in anywhere you can get the request, and let us know what request.__provided__.__iro__ outputs.

Comment: @vangheem the remove analytics layer was a test. I have pushed without this.

Comment: @DavidGlick Done if it can help.

Comment: Founded, there is a typo. The first who find it will have stack points !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

haha, silly typo.
in viewlets/configure.zcml, the viewlet is "AnalyticsTrackingViewlet", the one from collective.googleanalytics.

In your viewlets.py you overrides this class but the real name of your overriden class is "AnalyticsViewlet"

Thus when the zcml is loaded, it overrides c.google.AnalyticsTrackingViewlet with ... c.google.AnalyticsTrackingViewlet :D.

Simply change your zcml to use AnalyticsViewlet and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

That looks very hackish. Why not leave the upstream layer alone?

You should override via overrides.zcml. Once that works /without/ a layer restriction you can bind it to a clean layer interface.

Alternative strategy, don't override the upstream viewlet but hide it via GS and give your own viewlet a different name. Again, on a clean layer.

Comment: I know about overrides.zcml but I think this is weird to make an addon which require overrides.zcml. The only place I use this is when I need to do unload of components (like singing and dancing). So this solution is a workaround and valid only for project. Layer are the solution to change the behavior of existing viewlet, what I'm trying to achieve here.